# How to Add Field Between Two Existing Field in Shapefile

Tags: python, arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Can you please let me know if it is possible to add a new Field between two existing field using ArcPy?
For Example if I have "Name", "Area", fiels already in my shapefile can I add a new field called "Scope" between these two? so the table looks like "Name","Scope", "Area"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert a field between two existing fields in a shapefile.  you will have to create a whole new file and create it with the order that you want.

Comment: thanks Dan, but what do you mean by creating whole file? how can I do that?

Comment: It isn't that simple...you have to create a searchcursor, obtain the data from the fields that you want, order them in the order that you want then create an insertcursor putting the values where you want them.  You might look to see if there are free tools out there that might do it.  Check www.ian-ko.com and see if one of his toolsets allows for reordering fields.